# Bind AngularJS variables into inline script tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I have the need to add in some items from my scope into some inline script I need to run on my site.

From what I have tried in my demo it doesn't look possible to use the values from my scope in inline script tags.  What is the best way to achieve this?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        '{{aaa}}'
         <script>console.log('{{aaa}}');</script>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.aaa = 'bbb';
}]);
</script>
```

Console returns `'{{aaa}}'`. I want it to return `bbb`.

Comment: If you run your code snippet, you'll notice the output is `bbb`. Check for errors in your developer console.

Comment: @Sacho I get bbb once but if you look within the script tags this should also return bbb (in the console.log), instead it returns {{aaa}}?

Comment: Angular interpolates attributes or contents of dom elements - not javascript strings. If you want to interpolate a string, use the `$interpolate` service.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="idd" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        '{{aaa}}'
        <button ng-click="$log.log(aaa)">log</button>


    </div>
</div>
<script>
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$log', 
        function($scope,  $log) {
            $scope.aaa = 'bbb';
            $scope.$log = $log;
            //console.log($scope.aaa);
            //console.log($scope.$parent);
        }
    ]);
</script>
```

Comment: may be you try this to log it in console window..
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log